# I can't get Results from a Query in code behind in Silverlight Business Applications

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

regarding your book "Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4" there is something that makes me cumbersome. I'm Talking about getting results from a query in code behind. Suppossing you are using WCF RIA Services, you are always getting Nothing as a result due to asynchronous mecanism between Server and Client.
I've tried to use a BusyIndicator like this (VB), but it doesn't work:

```
dim ctx as new DomainService1
dim query= from p As Entity1 In Ctx.GetQueryEntity1Query select p 

If ctx.IsLoading = True Then
   BusyIndicator1.IsBusy = True
   Else
   BusyIndicator1.IsBusy = False
End If
```

How to stop the Program until the Server has completed the Load Operation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the entities using the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422589%28v=VS.91%29.aspx)-Method of the DomainContext class. This method expects a query to invoke and that specifies what entities to load.
The Load-Method returnes an instance of [LoadOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.loadoperation%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) that you can use to check if the load of the entities has finshed and to access the loaded entities.

Try to update your code as following:

```
dim ctx as new DomainService1
dim query= ctx.GetQueryEntity1Query
dim loadOperation = ctx.Load(query)

loadOperation.Completed += LoadCompleted
BusyIndicator1.IsBusy = True

Private Sub LoadCompleted(sender as object, e as EventArgs)
   BusyIndicator1.IsBusy = False
end Sub
```